# How to extract the number using perl in linux from the output displayed

Tags: linux, perl, shell, unix, jmx

```
# This Perl script open connection and call domains
# $jar stands for path of jmxterm jar file

open JMX, "| java -jar jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar -n"; // jmx jar file 
#print JMX "help \n";

my $host = "127.0.0.1"; // hostname
my $port = 7199; //jmx port number

print JMX "open $host:$port\n";
#print JMX "domains\n";
print JMX "domain org.apache.cassandra.request\n";
print JMX "bean type=ReadRepairStage\n";
print JMX "get CompletedTasks\n"; 
print JMX "close\n";
close JMX;
```

Currently I am getting the output as `CompletedTasks = 1234` and I need `1234`.

Comment: To where is that output coming? Standard output? If so, you must listen to choroba and consider a two-way communication solution.

Comment: thats Standard output. I am quite new to perl, how do i execute the jar if i use open2 and rewrite the above code ?

Comment: Look at the documentation, it should tell you how to use it. However, are you sure perl is the best tool here? If you don't know perl, and you're executing java, why add complication?

Comment: I need to execute the scripts in Cacti server. so , i need to write script either in perl or shell, to generate a graph in cacti.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use simple `open` to establish a two way communication. See [IPC::Open2](http://p3rl.org/IPC%3a%3aOpen2) for more.

Comment: thanks for the reply @choroba . but i only need to read the values from the bean and use the values to plot a graph

Answer (score 0):

[Jmx4Perl](http://www.jmx4perl.org) offers a full Perl API for accessing JMX information. No startup of an JVM is needed here, however an [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org) agent needs to be installed (but there is also an agentless [proxy mode](http://www.jolokia.org/features/proxy.html)).

You can easily use a pure shell script for accessing the Agent, too, since the agent exposes the JMX API over simple JSON and HTTP.